# adding encrypted /home in LVM/LUKS

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, luks, cryptsetup

I installed a new (debian) system to an SSD device. After standard install I want to mount `/home` on the internal HDD.

To be able to ask the question, some details: On install I (manually) generated `/dev/sdb5_crypt` in which sits a LVM with `/dev/mapper/SSD-root` holding the system. I tried

```
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived sdb5_crypt  | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda2 --key-file -
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived sdb5_crypt  | cryptsetup luksOpen  /dev/sda2 sda2_crypt --key-file -
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
mount /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt /home
```

It seems to work (although I have doubts if I should use `sdb5_crypt` or the `/dev/mapper/SSD-root` here). BUT: the second part, namely putting

in `/etc/crypttab`:

```
sda2_crypt /dev/sda2 sdb5_crypt luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived
```

and in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/sda2_crypt  /home ext4  defaults, noatime 0 2
```

does not work -- with these two lines in place I can no longer boot. Taking 'em out via rescue disc makes the system bootable again.

What did I do wrong? Should I integrate the new `/home` in the LVM first (and if so HOW do I do this)?